# 'cannot resolve symbol R' android studio error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Execution failed for task :`app:mergeDebugResources`.
What is this error and how to I fix it?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
         App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

This is my xml above... and below is `onCreate()` where         `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`
is causing the problem:

> cannot resolve symbol R

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}
```

Comment: `Clean-Rebuild-Restart` & import  `import  PackageName.R `

Comment: make sure all resource as same package in manifest .mainactivity is with red sign?

Comment: When you build your project there is no warning or error? Also try to close and open AS again, sometimes that works for me

Comment: Did you check are there any errors in xml files, Then cleaning the project and running should fix this !

Comment: Cleaning and running isn't fixing the problem. There are no errors in the xml. the only error is coming form the symbol R

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, If anyone need it

I was using gradle 3.3.0. It was the main culprit. Wasted 6.50 hours from my life. Gradle 3.2.1 removed the error.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me!! Ideally, Gradle plugin version given in script(build.gradle of project) should match gradle plugin version of IDE

Answer (score 3):

'cannot resolve symbol R' error usually occurs and the 'symbol R' turns red in color whenever the gradle sync is not completed. 
Hence before running any project it is always advisable to first sync the project if any dependencies or anything have been added and then clean the project and then run it.

It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`R` is predefined class in android.
you should clean your project and then build it again. it will resolve `R`.

Comment: Or there is an error somewhere that isn't obvious and it can't automatically be generated

Comment: But there are only two possibilities, either `R` is not imported properly or its not used properly. so in most of the cases it resolve using clean and build process.

Comment: A clean and a build won't fix improper layout xml, which causes R not to be generated, that's all I'm saying

Answer (score 1):

Go to the file directory.

1. Click "app"
2. Click "com.example.?????"
3. Right Click
4. Hover over "New"
5. Click on "Java Class"
6. Name the file "R" and leave the other things blank & accept the defaults
7. Click OK
   You have finished the first part!
8. Click File
9. Hover over "New"
10. Click "New Project"
11. Accept all defaults until you've reached the layout xml file
12. Click "app"
13. Click "com.example.android.?????"
14. Click "R"
15. Select all
16. Go back to your old file
17. Paste
18. Finished!

Answer (score 0):

probably your gradle sync failed , that is why it cannot be resolved resync the gradle or you have not imported `yourpackagename.R`;

Answer (score 0):

Only this solution worked for me:

1- Go to your app directory -> /app/src/main/res/

2- Delete folder XML (***Make sure that you don't have important files inside it***)

Answer (score 0):

Also i just found out if you have used an updated version of android studio like 4.2.2 and you want to go back to android studio 3.2.1 for example... the constraint layouts can also cause issues.
if you delete the constraints to each one like:
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" for one example it would successfully sync and this problem would be solved

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31847363)